# How to replace Strings in XML with values stored in different table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose there are two tables

TableA

```
Id XML

1 <A x="$Y" B="$Z" />
```

TableB

```
Id Key Value

1  $Y   100

1  $Z   200
```

Id columns in TableA and TableB can be joined.

The expected output is

```
TableA

Id XML

1 <A x="100" B="200" />
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's wrong with `REPLACE`?

Comment: @Larnu - Replace is not letting me make use of ID columns efficiently. I have to first get the String dynamically (understand where does $ start and when the quotes end) and then go to another table and then match the string. Considerably slow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956978/string-replacement-in-sql-server-using-the-contents-of-another-table-e-g-updat  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51835718/how-to-replace-substring-in-a-column-using-lookup-table-in-sql-server

Comment: @TabAlleman - Let me go through them.

Comment: @Larnu - Can we join these tables on a TableA.ID = TableB.ID in REPLACE function ?

Comment: inside the `REPLACE`, no; in your `FROM`, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link supplied by Tab Alleman does show you the basic idea here. You need to use `REPLACE` and a Recursive Common Table Expression (rCTE):

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (Id int,
                     [XML] xml);
CREATE TABLE TableB (Id int,
                     [Key] varchar(5),
                     [Value] varchar(20));
INSERT INTO dbo.TableA (Id,
                        [XML])
VALUES(1,'<A x="$Y" B="$Z" />');

INSERT INTO dbo.TableB (Id,
                        [Key],
                        [Value])
VALUES (1,'$Y','100'),
       (1,'$Z','200');
GO


WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT B.Id,
           B.[Key],
           B.[Value],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B.Id ORDER BY [Key]) AS RN
    FROM dbo.TableB B),
rCTE AS(
    SELECT A.Id,
           REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(MAX),A.[XML]),RN.[Key], RN.[Value]) AS [XML],
           RN.RN
    FROM dbo.TableA A
         JOIN RNs RN ON A.Id = RN.Id
    WHERE RN.RN = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.Id,
           REPLACE(r.[XML],RN.[Key], RN.[Value]) AS [XML],
           RN.RN
    FROM rCTE r
         JOIN RNs RN ON r.Id = RN.Id
                    AND RN.RN = r.RN + 1)
SELECT Id,
       CONVERT(xml,[xml]) AS [XML]
FROM rCTE r
WHERE RN = (SELECT MAX(RN) FROM rCTE E);

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.TableA;
DROP TABLE dbo.TableB;
```

As an `UPDATE` statement, this would like this:

```
WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT B.Id,
           B.[Key],
           B.[Value],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B.Id ORDER BY [Key]) AS RN
    FROM dbo.TableB B),
rCTE AS(
    SELECT A.Id,
           REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(MAX),A.[XML]),RN.[Key], RN.[Value]) AS [XML],
           RN.RN
    FROM dbo.TableA A
         JOIN RNs RN ON A.Id = RN.Id
    WHERE RN.RN = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.Id,
           REPLACE(r.[XML],RN.[Key], RN.[Value]) AS [XML],
           RN.RN
    FROM rCTE r
         JOIN RNs RN ON r.Id = RN.Id
                    AND RN.RN = r.RN + 1)
UPDATE A
SET [XML] = r.[XML]
FROM TableA A
     JOIN rCTE r oN A.Id = r.Id
WHERE RN = (SELECT MAX(RN) FROM rCTE E);
```

Comment: I am just trying to run update dbo.TableA
 set a.[XML] = REPLACE(convert (varchar(max),a.[XML]), b.[key], b.[value]) as [xml]
 from dbo.tablea a
 inner join dbo.tableb b
 on a.id = b.id but it says invalid syntax near 'as', isn't it intending to do the same operation ?

Comment: You don't alias a column in an `UPDATE` statement, @Gsab

Comment: I've added an `UPDATE` version for you, @Gsab

Comment: @Larnu- fixed the statement like update dbo.TableA
 set [XML] = REPLACE(convert (varchar(max),a.[XML]), b.[key], b.[value])
 from dbo.tablea a
 inner join dbo.tableb b
 on a.id = b.id , but what i have observed is that only the first key got replaced with its value and not the second

Comment: It works fine for me, @Gsab: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=18672e453483d0fbd149498749b3d2b7)

Comment: when we run just the update statement without actually going for a recursive cte. I mean just single update statement, it only replaces first key. Standalone statement like update dbo.TableA set [XML] = REPLACE(convert (varchar(max),a.[XML]), b.[key], b.[value]) from dbo.tablea a inner join dbo.tableb b on a.id = b.id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198958/discussion-between-gsab-and-larnu).

Comment: well yes, @Gsab, if you exclude the rCTE of source it won't work correctly... That's why there's an rCTE...